# How do I add in groups with r?

Tags: r

I want to calculate sum of columns and rows 'by groups'.

For example,

`a <- matrix(c(NA, NA, "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "a", 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1,  "a", 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,  "a", 3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, "b", 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3,  "b", 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0), ncol = 7, nrow = 7)`

I have a square matrix like data 'a'.

|  |  |  | a | a | a | b | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| a | 1 |  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| a | 2 |  | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| a | 3 |  | 3 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| b | 4 |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| b | 5 |  | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

The thing I need to do is to change the matrix like this

|  |  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a |  | 13 | 7 |
| b |  | 4 | 4 |

The point is that I do not need the rows&columns of numbers. I just need the alphabet rows&columns. For example, the original matrix has values.
`1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 2-1, 2-2, 2-3, 3-1, 3-2, 3-3`

All of these 9 values need to be added up. So they become 13.

To solve this problem, I tried aggregate function. But I didn't success.

Comment: the AB should be 7, not 12 on your result matrix no?

Comment: Oh, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowsum` twice and use once `t` to transpose the matrix to sum it up per group in both directions.

```
x <- matrix(as.numeric(a[3:7, 3:7]), 5, dimnames=list(a[3:7,1], a[1,3:7]))

y <- t(rowsum(x, rownames(x)))
rowsum(y, rownames(y))
#   a b
#a 13 7
#b  4 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't thought of using t() function.